What's the meaning of Paul's vision of Leto I alongside a skull?
At Sietch Tabr, while eating with Jessica, Paul experiences a fleeting vision of Fremen
paying homage to a portrait of Leto I alongside a skull:

What's the meaning of this vision?

The skull belongs to his father. Paul is beginning to see visions of things to come and things that might become. He's not entirely sure whether he's already done some of the things described.

Yet Chani was deep in the south — in the cold country where the sun
was hot – secreted in one of the new sietch strongholds, safe with
their son, Leto II.
Or, was that a thing yet to happen?
No, he reassured himself, for Alia-the-Strange-One, his sister, had
gone there with his mother and with Chani — a twenty-thumper trip into
the south, riding a Reverend Mother’s palanquin fixed to the back of a
wild maker.
He shied away from thought of riding the giant worms, asking himself:
Or is Alia yet to be born?
I was on razzia, Paul recalled. We went raiding to recover the water
of our dead in Arrakeen. And I found the remains of my father in the
funeral pyre. I enshrined the skull of my father in a Fremen rock
mound overlooking Harg Pass.
Or was that a thing yet to be? My wounds are real, Paul told himself.
My scars are real. The shrine of my father’s skull is real.
Dune

